# Android Emulator Not Take Internet Permissions

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-permissions

My Android emulators not taking internet permission.

My Manifest File;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.codework.myapplication">

    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat Error;

> AndroidManifest Error: WebView login requires INTERNET permission

In Settings - No permissions requested;

[image: No permissions requested]

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

With

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: ah.. easy solution. Thank you.. My bad.

Comment: @EmreErol always welcome bro don't worry it happened some time bro

Answer (score 2):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

NOT

permission ...